# Passing date as string to textview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parameter-passing

I have a problem with passing a string to my fragment java class. I kept getting null value even though it is declared and set to appear on textview.

```
TextView date;
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    date.setText(mydate);
```

I've inserted this line on my onCreateView

```
        date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
```

Here's the rest of the code for reference:

```
public class Notifications extends Fragment {
    TextView servingqueue;
    TextView date;

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mServingQueue = mRootRef.child("ServingQueue");


public Notifications() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        date.setText(mydate);

    mServingQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Double number = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
            servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragmentid.queueServing);
    servingqueue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.queueServing);
        date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Here's the error showing on my log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at rogue.queue.Notifications.onCreateView(Notifications.java:74)
```

Here's the fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="rogue.queue.Notifications"
android:id="@+id/notification_relative_layout">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:text="Your Number:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/myqueue"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Current Number:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myqueue"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/myqueue" />

<TextView
    android:text="PLEASE BE SEATED"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/queueServing"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/queueServing"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/myqueue" />

<TextView
    android:text="YOU WILL BE SERVED SHORTLY"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Welcome to Sunway Education Group"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:id="@+id/textDate"
    tools:text="00 - JAN - 0000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9" />

<Button
    android:text="CANCEL QUEUE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonQueueCancel"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    />
```

Comment: Check fragment lifecycle in the android docs.

Comment: `onCreateView` is called after `onCreate`, so `date` hasn't been set when you're trying to use it. Try finding and setting the text on `date` from within the `onViewCreated` method instead.

Comment: @clownba0t Same error, i still get Attempt to invoke virtual method null object reference error.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace that you are seeing. Please also post the layout file `R.layout.fragment_notifications`.

Comment: @clownba0t edited main post to show the error. fragment notifications contain the usual elements along with the textview id named textDate.

Comment: Thanks. The code you're running has obviously changed since it was posted above - please update the code in your question to match what you're the code in its current state.

Comment: Also, the error is coming from `onCreateView` - I suggested finding and setting the text of `date` in `onViewCreated`. These are different methods. I've posted an answer below with some sample code of what it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, try finding the text view and setting its value in the `onViewCreated` method. Please note that this is different to the `onCreateView` method which you are already using. Here's some example code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
}
```

Also, to aid in debugging, please make sure that the `date` member variable is not being set or used anywhere else in the class, at least for now.

Comment: Thanks. I inserted this, and there was no error. But the string did not pass its values to the textview, hence the textview remains empty.

Comment: Okay, well, that's hopefully a step in the right direction. The remaining issue could be being caused by any of a number of things. If you would like further assistance, again, please post your layout file (`R.layout.fragment_notifications`) and update your question with the current code of the `Notifications` class.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out your layout locally, and it seems that the `textDate` `TextView` is actually being displayed underneath the "CANCEL QUEUE" button. That's why you can't see the text, even after it's been set correctly. At least for now, try removing the `android:layout_marginTop="68dp"` attribute from it in the XML file. That should at least bring it onto the screen so you can see it, and then you can position it correctly.

Comment: Fixed! the xml is the issue here. I removed the layout_marginTop and the date is visible. This is a rookie mistake. :) Thanks man.

Comment: Okay, i realised that by placing those additional lines on onViewCreated, it changes the time&date everytime i move to this fragment. I want the date to stay static and remain unchanged. How do i do that?

Comment: Great to hear. Regarding your subsequent question, it's a different topic to your original question so I don't think it'd be appropriate for me to answer it here. Not to mention that I think you should do some of your own research into it first :) If you still can't work it out, consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is, check if your TextView can be found succesfully.

```
date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
if (date == null)
    Log.e("x", "NOT FOUND");
```

See if this log line appears. If yes, `R.id.textDate` is not your `TextView` or `rootView` is the wrong parent.

If you can be sure, your TextView is found, I'd suggest to create a method instead of setting the date reference in eventcallback 1 and assigning something in callback2.

Like this:

```
private void applyTextValues(Date date, float queueValue) {
    TextView 
        date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textDate),
        servingqueue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.queueServing);

        if (date != null)
            date.setText(...); // Format this via SimpleDateFormat class

        if (servingQueue != null) 
            servingQueue.setText(...); // Format your number.

}
```

And then you call `applyTextValues` in the change event, in onCreate and where ever you need it. This way you are independant of any life cycles, any deallocations from Android side, any Activity-related actions. When you call this method you get the most current reference *right here* and you are done.

Comment: I tried out your log method but I kept getting error the moment i click to that fragment. The error happens at date.setText(mydate); pointing to Null Object reference.

Comment: - removed as question is solved already - sorry didn't see it -